# Почему Spring Data делает лишние запросы?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Есть следующий метод JPA репозитория:

```
@Query("select new com.example.sweater.domain.dto.MessageDto(" +
        "   m, " +
        "   count(ml), " +
        "   sum(case when ml = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0" +
        ") " +
        "from Message m left join m.likes ml " +
        "group by m")
Page<MessageDto> findAll(Pageable pageable, @Param("user") User user);
```

Проблема: помимо одного запроса, который указан в аннотации `@Query`, в базу еще летят запросы на выборку КАЖДОГО сообщения отдельно.

Вопрос: почему так происходит и как с этим бороться?

Весь код доступен на [github](https://github.com/drucoder/sweater).

**UPD1:** Лог запросов:

```
Hibernate: select message0_.id as col_0_0_, count(user2_.id) as col_1_0_, sum(case when user2_.id=? then 1 else 0 end)>0 as col_2_0_ from message message0_ left outer join message_likes likes1_ on message0_.id=likes1_.message_id left outer join usr user2_ on likes1_.user_id=user2_.id group by message0_.id order by message0_.id desc limit ?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select count(message0_.id) as col_0_0_ from message message0_ left outer join message_likes likes1_ on message0_.id=likes1_.message_id left outer join usr user2_ on likes1_.user_id=user2_.id group by message0_.id
```

**UPD2:** Еще заметил, что когда я пытаюсь передать в MessageDto(m,...), то вместо m передается не объект сообщения, как мне надо, а id этого сообщения. Может по этому hibernate ходит в базу за каждым сообщением?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на проблему `N+1 selects`. Она возникает, когда вы делаете `select` связанной, родительской, сущности у которой также имеется ссылка на данный объект. `Hibernate` делает дополнительные селекты для того чтобы вытащить все связи. Поэтому сначала `Hibernate` вытащит все `N` записией родителей, а затем, для каждого по отдельности запросит связные сущности.

Для того чтобы решить данную проблему можно либо явно указать `join` всех связей в `@Query` или же для всех связей включить кэш второго уровня:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Message> messages;
}
```

Проблема в том, что ваши `Message` и `User` содержит ссылку друг на друга.

Когда вы указываете `FetchType.LAZY`, это не означает что он вообще не будет запрашивать все `N` связей, просто он сделает `N` select'ов, когда вы обратитесь к этому полю.

Comment: Но ведь куча лишних селектов вытягивает не какую то связь из Message, а они вытягивают именно сами мессаджи. Добавил аннотацию @Cache, но ничего не изменилось, столько же запросов.

Comment: @WenSiL Мессаджи вытягиваются, потому что сначала вытаскиваются юзеры, а затем для каждого юзера вытаскиваются мессаджи. `@Cache` и `@Cacheable` добавили на оба класса User и Message?

Comment: если `@Cacheable` нужно было навесить на класс Message, то да. Это не дает результата. Но, если честно, я вас не понимаю. Причем тут юзеры, если в findAll я передаю юзера уже заранее вытянутого из базы? Если посмотреть лог запросов, то никаких юзеров там нет. А какой второй вариант? В `@Query` для findAll нужно будет еще добавить join User?

Comment: Еще заметил, что когда я пытаюсь передать в MessageDto(m,...), то вместо m передается не объект сообщения, как мне надо, а id этого сообщения. Может по этому hibernate ходит в базу за каждым сообщением?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать аннотацию `@NamedEntityGraph`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
@NamedEntityGraph(name="allMessages", attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("messages")
    })
public class User implements UserDetails {
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Message> messages;
...
}
```

затем используйте этот граф в репозитории

```
@EntityGraph(value = "allMessages" , type=EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
Page<MessageDto> findAll(Pageable pageable, @Param("user") User user);
```

Вы можете использовать несколько NamedEntityGraph с разным набором полей, тем самым получая всегда только те поля которые вам сейчас действительно нужны за один запрос